# Rails 3.2.6 and dbi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, dbi, incompatibility

I have a small rails app, which was running fine with Ruby 1.8x and Rails
2.x.  In a regrettable decision, I decided to move to Ruby 1.9.x and Rails 3, 
and it's a glorious pain.

My Ruby app uses MySQL, and I use Active Record for that.
However there is an earlier pgm I had written to fill in the database
before I did Rails (2.x), which is part of the complete application now.
(I can test/run the standalone pgm outside Rails and there is no
problem.)

This standalone program is using MySQL and dbi gems.  I call this program as such from a model:

```
 system("ruby standalonepgm.rb -args ")
```

In Rails 2.0 this works without any issues.
In 3.0 the program exits without any way to capture the error.

Running under console I see that the program dies because it can't find the
dbi gem!

If I put the dbi gem in the Gemfile and do bundle date, then there is
real trouble.  Rails refuses to start - the rails server dies with all kind of issues.
I can put in the screendump, but I think that's unimportant.

There seem to be 2 issues:

1. DBI is surely incompatible with the gods of Rails
2. Rails creates a sandbox, and all programs called must live in that
   sandbox (that's why just a require statement doesn't suffice .. it has to be in Gemfile).

Is it fixable or I am one of those who got bitten by the hidden black magic of rails, and my past 8+ weeks of effort is down the tubes?

Comment: Two follow-on questions.  1 - what errors do you get?  2 - Have you checked that dbi is compatible with the new version of Rails?  (As an aside, it's never advisable to upgrade to a new language platform unless you can be certain that everything is compatible.)

Comment: It's fixed by using Bundle.with_clean_env do system("ruby pgm.rb" end

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer, but never think Rails has any magic associated with it. It is all plain old Ruby; magic is just code you haven't bothered to understand.

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed by using 
Bundle.with_clean_env do
 system("ruby pgm.rb" 
end

I had never read bundle doc ..this case is described in it ..